# How to get an key value pair from an object in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

sample array:

```
  const obj = {
    "29": "DTE Queue",
    "30": "Services Reporting Sales",
    "31": "Services Reporting Ops",
    "41": "UPLOAD",
    "55": "Support Report"
  };
```

I'm getting input from user as 'ser'. Then output should be { "30": "Services Reporting Sales", "31": "Services Reporting Ops"}.But the output I'm getting is {"30": "Services Reporting Sales"}.

**Method 1:**

```
 getKeyByValue(obj:object, value) {
  const matchedEntry = Object.entries(obj).find(entry => 
  entry[1].toLowerCase().match(value.toLowerCase()));
  return matchedEntry &&(<any>Object).fromEntries([matchedEntry])
}
```

**Method2:**

```
getKeyByValue(obj: Object, value) {
    try {
      return (<any>Object).fromEntries([
        Object.entries(obj).find(([key, val]) =>
          val.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
        ),
      ]);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Object not found");
      return {};
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `find`. And directly use `.fromEntries(matchedEntry)`

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _" Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals."_ Don't use `obj:object`, `obj:Object` or `<any>Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `find`. `find` returns the first search result. If you want multiple results, you can use `filter`.

```js
const obj = {"29": "DTE Queue", "30": "Services Reporting Sales", "31": "Services Reporting Ops", "41": "UPLOAD", "55": "Support Report"};

function getObjectByValue(object, value) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(([key, val]) => val.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())));
}

console.log(getObjectByValue(obj, 'ser'));
console.log(getObjectByValue(obj, 'sup2'));
```

Comment: Thanks jabaa ,it worked like a gem. I'm new here so I made wrong tags.